# Why doesn't the map in my Google map line up with it's container

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, rendering

I have added a map to one of my pages but the contents don't line up with the container, I tried the same map in a stand alone page and it works fine.

The map renders like this: [enter link description here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zV2cRk8IsRE/UXqagbjPRzI/AAAAAAAAJCY/jdgoTUTWAaQ/s800/Capture.PNG)

The Map is actually centered on London so it looks like and lignment issue, but I haven't been able to fix it. Here's the function that creates the map:

```
function loadMap(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        thisLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log("location = " + thisLocation);
        var tagem = new google.maps.LatLng(thisLocation);
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.51121389999999, -0.11982439999997041),
            zoom:5,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:tagem,animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE});
        marker.setMap(map);
    }else{
        console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to tell the map to resize. Add this to the end of your loadMap() function:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Comment: I added this but I get "TypeError: a is undefined" on line 18 of main.js (the maps javascript). Same thing if i wait for the map to be idle before resizing.